# how can i show modal but not interrupt my cursor when clicking other button using jquery

Tags: jquery

I customized my own modal from bootstrap and show the modal when the server returns successful message. So what I want to happen is that when the modal will show it will just show and my cursor will not be interrupted. In my case, when the modal will show I can't click to another button until I click my mouse first for the modal to hide so I can click the button.

how can I achieve this using jQuery?

thanks...

Comment: This behavior is the definition of modal. You need another component if you don't want to block everything when the window is open

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean by "not interrupt cursor" - are you saying you're in an `<input>` then some background task makes an ajax call and the response of that is a "modal" which you want to display but still allow the user to edit the current input, but *not* change the input to another/click a button?  Even though the "modal" may be shown over the current input?  Sounds like a strange UX.  Or did you mean show the "modal" but still let the user interact with the page?  That sounds like a `toast notification` - check out [toastr](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/toastr/info)

Comment: toast notification is new to me, thanks for the information  freedomn-m, this is what I meant. thankss...